# Hackerearth challenge - Roy and Code Streak

Tags: c++, programming-challenge

> Roy is working on HackerEarth Profile. Right now he is working on User
>   Statistics. One of the statistics data (Code Streak) is as follows:
>
> Given the User Activity Data, find the maximum number of continuous
>   correct solutions submitted by any user. Seems easy eh? Here's the
>   catch! In order to maximize this number a user could have submitted a
>   correct answer to the same problem which he has already solved. Now
>   such cases cannot be tolerated. (See test case for clarification).
>   Also in all the continuous correct submissions multiple correct
>   submissions to same problem should be counted only once.
>
> User Activity Data will be as follows: Total number of submissions by
>   the user - N For each submission its Submission ID - S and Result - R
>   (Solved or Unsolved) will be given. Solved is represented by integer 1
>   and Unsolved by 0.
>
> Input: First line contains integer T - number of test cases. T test
>   cases follow. First line of each test case will contain N. Next N
>   lines each will contain two space separated integers S and R.
>
> Ouput: For each test case output in a single line the required answer.
>
> Constraints: 
>   1 <= T <= 1000
>   1 <= N <= 1000000 (10^6)
>   1 <= S <= 1000000 (10^6) 
>   0 <= R <= 1

```
Sample Input
3
6
1 0
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 1
6 0
5
1 1
2 0
3 1
1 1
2 1
4
1 1
2 1
2 1
3 1

Sample Output
4
2
3
```

Problem [Link](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/roy-and-code-streak/)

How to improve this code with more use of advance C++ features and to improve time complexity.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    unsigned int t, n, s, r;

    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        unsigned int count = 0, max_count = 0;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        std::vector<bool> status(1000000, false);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            scanf("%d%d", &s, &r);
            if (r == 1 && status[s] == false) {
                count++;
                status[s] = true;
            }
            else if (r == 0) {
                count = 0;
            }
            max_count = std::max(count, max_count);
        }
        printf("%d\n", max_count);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the use of `std::vector<bool> status(1000000, false);` in your solution at all. How does that help to solve the problem when defined within the `while` loop? Also hardcoding `1000000` elements looks not right for me. Did your code pass the test cases when submitted?

Comment: Yeah, my code submitted successfully for all test cases.

Comment: I looked at some of your other questions, you know the proper way to do input and output in C++, why are you using scanf and printf?

Comment: @pacmaninbw I have read on a codeforces blog that they are fast compared to `cin` and `cout`.

Comment: Why do you go to competitive programming sites anyway if you want to actually write good C++ code?  [Learning C++ from "competitive programming" is like learning English from a rap contest.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `printf` and `scanf`.  They are not faster, sometimes *slower*, and prone to undefined behavior.  Use I/O streams instead.  In fact, **every single call to `printf` and `scanf` in your code is undefined behavior** — you are consistently using `%d` to print `unsigned int`s.

You can call

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

before doing any I/O operation to turn off synchronization with `cstdio`, making the streams faster.

> @pacmaninbw I have read on a codeforces blog that they are fast
>   compared to `cin` and `cout`. –
>   [coder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/130800/coder) [16
>   hours
>   ago](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230967/hackerearth-challenge-roy-and-code-streak#comment450236_230967)

Disregard it.  "Competitive programming style C++" is a completely different language than the correct, proper C++.  [Learning C++ from "competitive programming" is like learning English a rap contest.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by advanced c++ features, but you could use an `std::unordered_set` to store the submission id.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    unsigned int t, n, s, r;
    std::unordered_set<int> seen;

    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        unsigned int count = 0, max_count = 0;

        seen.clear();

        scanf("%d", &n);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            scanf("%d%d", &s, &r);

            if (seen.count(s) == 0) {
                if (r == 1) {
                    count++;
                }
                seen.insert(s);
            }
            if (r == 0) {
                count = 0
            }
            max_count = std::max(count, max_count);
        }
        printf("%d\n", max_count);
    }
}
```

I'm not at a PC with a C++ compiler, so this hasn't been tested.